# Creating shapes in the OpenTK library in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, shapes, opentk

So I am doing an oil pipeline simulation project which has three windows; the stats window (for pipeline details), the simulation window (for details about how the pipeline will work and the middle window- the 2D simulation of the oil pipeline.

The 2D simulation is in fact, there for aesthetic purposes- the main nitty-gritty is done within the Maths.cs class that I have already programmed. So my question is this:

Using shapes in the OpenTK library, all I can seem to build is triangles. I've inserted the code used to build the triangle but otherwise there seems to be no other shapes. Is there any way I can draw a 1) Circle, 2) Rectangle and 3) Line?

Also, what does the 'BeginMode' class do? I feel this would crack the problem, by using something other than BeginMode I can access other shapes through a different class??

Thanks :-)

```
    private void viewportGL_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!loaded)
            return;

        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        GL.Translate(x, 0, 0);

        GL.Color3(Color.Aqua);
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
        GL.Vertex2(10, 20);
        GL.Vertex2(100, 20);
        GL.Vertex2(100, 50);
        GL.End();

        viewportGL.SwapBuffers();

    }

    int x = 0;
    private void viewportGL_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            x+=4;
        viewportGL.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: There is no primitive like a circle but you can build it by defining multiple triangles between Begin() and End().

Comment: Would you be able to provide the source code to do that please? I'm having real trouble. :(

Answer (score 0):

So i will now extend to an answer:

```
float step = (float) Math.PI/10;
GL.Color3(Color.Aqua);
GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);
for (float angle = 0.0f; angle < Math.PI*2 - 0.001f; angle += step) {
    GL.Vertex2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL.Vertex2(Math.Cos(angle), Math.Sin(angle));
    GL.Vertex2(Math.Cos(angle - step), Math.Sin(angle - step));
}
GL.End();
```

BeginMode is an Enum and it basically tells OpenGL about the input primitive type. I think PrimitiveType does the same thing but one could argue that its meaning is more intuitive. For a rectangle you could write:

```
GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
GL.Vertex2(-0.5f, -0.5f);
GL.Vertex2( 0.5f, -0.5f);
GL.Vertex2( 0.5f,  0.5f);
GL.Vertex2(-0.5f,  0.5f);
GL.End();
```

By the way you may want to take a look at The OpenTK Manual:
http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics

Comment: Looks like OpenTK changed their domain, the new site available at https://opentk.net/api/index.html